# Create an empty framebox with specific with and length

Tags: boxes, width, height

I am looking a package to create an empty framebox of 2.7 cm height and 15.97 cm lenght. I am using `\framebox` but I am able only to set the size.

```
\framebox[15.97cm][l]{}
```

Answer (score 5):

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\frame{\rule{0pt}{2.7cm}\rule{15.97cm}{0pt}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `\fbox` or `\framebox`, you need to remember that it adds a gap and rule around it's contents. Remove this from your construction to ensure that the width/height is exactly what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\exactframe}[2]{%
  \fbox{%
    \rule{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{0pt}% width
    \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#2-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% height
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent \rule{15.97cm}{2.7cm}

\noindent \exactframe{15.97cm}{2.7cm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old post, but for anybody like me, who stumbled upon it and wants to try to use \exactframe, there is a minor error in Werner's code above. It should be:

```
\newcommand{\exactframe}[2]{%
  \fbox{%
    \rule{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{0pt}% width
    \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#2-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}% height
  }%
}
```

Regardless, thank you for the idea.