# Framed boxes with borders that take up no space (like the effect of `outline` CSS property)

Tags: boxes, rules, framed, layout, css

I would like to make some simple schemas using stacked or overlapping framed boxes with content. I could almost use a table instead, but I do not see how to do some of the "overlaps" in a table.

The problem with framed boxes is that if I put two of them side by side, their borders will combine to make a line of double thickness, but I want the borders to completely overlap to have lines of the same thickness on all sides.  In CSS this behaviour can be achieved using [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) and [outline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset) properties.

How to make framed boxes where frames take up no space in the layout?

Comment: I had some luck with `\framebox` but I'm not sure that it meets or I understand your goal. Would you be able to mock up something like the results you're looking for and add that?

Comment: @BHos, i mean that stacked boxes should look like a table/grid, with lines of the same width everywhere (no double thickness between cells).

Comment: You could draw your own box-grid maybe: using `\rule`s: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464865/create-an-empty-framebox-with-specific-with-and-length

Comment: TikZ would be a more practical method, in the long run: each box would have, say, topleft corner as anchor node. But there is a learning curve.

Comment: @Cicada, indeed, I ended up using TikZ.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building your box grid by hand, use kerning to adjust for the frame rule width, and \strut for uniform height+depth by row.

[image: rows]

Likewise vertically, for columns, `adjustbox` will help.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ns[1]{{\normalsize #1}}


\begin{document}
\Huge
\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}

\fbox{xyz}\fbox{xyz}\ns{next to each other}

\fbox{xyz}\kern-\fboxrule\fbox{xyz}\ns{kerned by -\textbackslash fboxrule}

\fbox{xyz}\fbox{abc}\ns{depth, height}

\fbox{\strut xyz}\fbox{\strut abc}\ns{strut}

\fbox{\strut xyz}\kern-\fboxrule\fbox{\strut abc}\ns{strut, kerned}

\end{document}
```